# Umbraco - Current node image

Tags: image, umbraco7

I'm trying to get an image from the current node, in Umbraco. I know the way I'm using it is not the best, but I'm trying to understand something. Here is my code :

```
var image = Node.GetCurrent().GetProperty("image").Value.ToString();
var url = @Umbraco.Media(image).Url;
```

First, I'm getting the `Image` value :  `umb://media/b59274b4328f4f39866144bef8edef58`

From this value, I'm trying to get the Url, but my `var url` is empty.

But, when I try :

```
@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("image").ToString()).Url
```

Everything is working.

I don't understand this.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question. Am I right in understanding that you have picked media with a media picker called "image"? And then you are trying to get the url to that picked media file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've not found the why.

I really want someone to answer me why this is not working.

I've found a workaround :

```
@CurrentPage.Image.Url
```

Thanks !